# 4 simultaneous equations, 3 unknowns, How do I know I've found all the solutions?

Tags: algebra-precalculus, systems-of-equations

$$4x-y-z=21$$
$$2x+4y+z=69$$
$$8x+y-z=81$$
$$-4x+7y+3z=57$$
Solutions are $y=30-2x$ and $z=6x-51$ according to wolfram alpha and it's quite simple to get to these solutions and then check that they are consistent with all 4 equations.

My question is how do I know that there are no other ways to express $y$ and $z$. Also, why are the solutions completely contained inside the $x-y$ and $x-z$ planes?

Comment: Replace x in the first equation of solution with z and you get another representation of y. So there is more way to express y. But if you want to express y and z, then there is one solution. Suppose there is some other expression for y represented by f(x). But then f(x) must equal 30-2x.

Comment: If I understand you correctly, you are saying that I could express y in terms of z? Also, any other expression in terms of x for y would just equal 30-2x as they represent the same variable y. I see what you mean about f(x) and I assume this reasoning extends to z also. Thank you very much.

Comment: Yes, you can use x,y,z or even some t as parameter. e.g. $t=2x$. So there is infinite way to express x,y and z.

Comment: Consider that in three dimensions, each equation represents a plane. The solution is the line that forms the intersections of those two planes. The thing is, you can't describe a line (or curve) in $\mathbb{R}^3$ with one function $f(x,y,z)$. Three equations in parametric form is more common. Here, you could let $x$ be equivalent to the parameter $t$, and write $\{x = t, y = -2t+30, z=6t-51\}$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do a Guassian Elimination for the equation set:
$$4x-y-z=21$$
$$2x+4y+z=69$$
$$8x+y-z=81$$
$$-4x+7y+3z=57$$
Then
$$4x-y-z=21$$
$$4.5y+1.5z=58.5$$
$$3y+z=39$$
$$6y+2z=78$$
Then
$$4x-y-z=21$$
$$4.5y+1.5z=58.5$$
$$0=0$$
$$0=0$$
Then you can write down the solution use y or z as parameter. If you elimination y or z at the beginning. You can use x as parameter and get the same result as wolfram alpha.
The solution is a line in 3-d. It is not contains in $x-y$ plane or $x-z$ plane neither $y-z$ plane. I know the answer is a line since Guassian Elimination left 2 independent equation with 3 variable. There is 1 more variable then equation.